# How can I make tcpdump stop the capture after a certain number of packets captured?

Tags: linux, tcpdump

I am debugging a problem where two servers get stuck in a loop when communicates with each other. After a server restart the problem will start at some point, it can be in an hour
or in a day. I want to tcpdump the traffic when the problem starts so I can find out what
makes it happen.

My plan is to restart the servers then let tcpdump capture the traffic and then analyze the
result. However I would like tcpdump to stop after a few thousand packets captured to
avoid having to monitor it, since I don't know when the traffic will start.

Anyone having a suggestion?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See `man tcpdump`:

> -c     Exit after receiving count packets.

Comment: I am not sure how I could have missed that in the man page.

Answer (score -2):

Type the command below:

```
sudo tcpdump -i eno1 -c [size]
```

The argument `-i eno1` tells tcpdump to listen only on the `eno1` interface, and `-c [size]` tells tcpdump to stop capturing after [size] packages have been captured. So `tcpdump -i eno1 -c 2048` will stop after 2048 packages.

Comment: you might want to add what parameter does what, especially given that the interface -i is not always named what you typed.

Additionally the answer to the question is already accepted including the source so your answer seems not to add anything relevant to the question, which might be the reason you got downvoted.